# How to do lazy export in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules

Module: shared-module

```
export * from "./common-types";
export * from "./lots-of-large-classes"
```

Let's say I have 200 large classes and import the above module like

Module: Main

```
import { CommonTypeClass } from "shared-module"
```

Now all 200 classes "also" will load as they are resolved in static scope and referred in my import.

To avoid this I tried

```
Object.defineProperty(module.exports, 'lots-of-large-classes', {
    // The lots-of-large-classes folder is very large. To avoid pulling it in from static
    // scope, we lazy-load  the module.
    get: () => require('./lots-of-large-classes'),
});
```

But VS Code isn't showing the lots-of-large-classes import.

```
import { LargeClassOne } from 'shared-module/lots-of-large-classes';  // ISN'T WORKING
```

However, above solution also still loads all classes as there is an index file which loads all classes.

How can I selective load LargeClassOne from lots-of-large-classes folder without loading other classes through shared-module?
Something like with overhead of loading one large class alone which is being imported.

```
import { LargeClassOne } from 'shared-module/lots-of-large-classes';
```

Comment: you could always import them directly from their file instead of from the index

Comment: Vscode pointing to dist folder which i want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to statically import dynamically-loaded data. Using [subpath exports](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/packages.html#subpath-exports) in the `package.json` for `"shared-module"` will help you accomplish your goal.

You can combine this with TypeScript's [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) feature for very flexible import specifiers.

Comment: subpaths sounds interesting! Can you please share how to apply to the above example?

Comment: Looks like its not supported yet for typescript??
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079

Comment: @Ayyappa I updated my answer to include information about the path mapping feature in TSConfig. Because you didn't provide a [minmal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I can't provide specifics for your scenario, but the documentation explains how you can apply it.